# PostgresQL with TypeORM can I achieve composite primary keys from 3 entities in a Junction table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, typeorm

I have three entities as follows

```js
@Entity()
@Unique(['id'])
export class Model {
  @PrimaryColumn('uuid')
  id: string

  // ...
}



@Entity()
export class Element {
   @PrimaryColumn()
   elementId: string
   
   @ManyToOne(() => Model, (model) => model.elements)
   @JoinColumn({ name: 'modelId', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
   modelId: string
   
   // ...   
}


@Entity()
@Unique(['rowNum'])
@Unique('unique_pks_1', ['rowNum', 'modelId'])
export class BoqRow {
   @PrimaryColumn()
   rowNum: number
   
   @ManyToOne(() => Model, (model) => model.boqRows, { primary: true })
   @JoinColumn({ name: 'modelId', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
   modelId: string
   
   // ...
}
```

no problems so far, what I am trying to achieve now is to have a junction table that would connect the above three entities in the following manner

```js
@Entity()
@Unique('unique_pks_2', ['rowNum', 'modelId', 'elementId'])
export class BoqRowToElement {
   @ManyToOne(() => Model, (model) => model.boqRowToElements, { primary: true })
   @JoinColumn({ name: 'modelId', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
   modelId!: string

   @ManyToOne(() => BoqRow, (boqRow) => boqRow.boqRowToElements, { primary: true })
   @JoinColumn({ name: 'rowNum', referencedColumnName: 'rowNum' })
   rowNum!: number

   @ManyToOne(() => Element, (element) => element.boqRowToElements, { primary: true })
   elementId!: string
}
```

I am not really sure if this design is the best or is it even correct but I was able to run this code and have the tables reflect in the db. but I am trouble inserting into this junction table using TypeORM.
Thanks.